# Leading Zeroes - Print digits of a number in words

Tags: c, int

I need a C program that will print the digits of an entered number using `switch` statements.

For example:-  if I enter '001' as the value, it should print `zero zero one` as the output.

I know how to print number to words of other numbers, ie, first reverse the number, then extract digit using modulus operator and then print the words using switch conditions.

By default `C` takes the value `001` as `1` automatically. How can I stop that? I want to print the leading zeroes also.

Answer (score 1):

To have leadings zeros, you can take a string as input. If you want, afterwards, you can extract the number from your string with `atoi` ou `strto*`.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char buf[SIZE];
const char *text_number[] = { 
    "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", 
    "seven", "eight", "nine"
};

if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) != NULL) {
    char *peol = strchr(buf, '\n');

    if (peol != NULL) {
        size_t size = peol - buf; /* assume `peol` is a valid pointer */

        for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            switch (buf[i]) {
            case '0': 
            case '1': 
            case '2': 
            case '3': 
            case '4': 
            case '5':
            case '6':
            case '7':
            case '8':
            case '9':
                putchar(text_number[buf[i]]);
                break;
            default:
                /* treat "not a digit" error */
            }
        }
        putchar('\n');
    } else {
        /* treat strchr error */
    }
} else {
    /* treat fgets error */
}
```

Comment: like save the number to a character string? I knew that. Is it possible to print zeroes when the input number has leading zeroes like I said in the example?

Comment: Then, you can run through your string. If it is a number, you can print it. I'll give an example.

Comment: Okay, I understand that.I guess it's not possible to do that with an integer variable right?

Comment: I think so. Because the memory representation of `001` and `1` are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Scan the input like an string and while printing do it as letters using the ASCII representation, something like this (only the idea):

```
int main (void)
{
   char number[ 30 ];
   int i = 0;

   printf( "Enter the number: " );

   /*You should use fgets here for safe scan*/
   scanf( "%s", number );


   while( *( number + i ) != '\0' ){
   switch( *( number + i) ){
      i++;

      /* Cause numbers are stored in their ASCII code*/
      case 48: /* 0 */
         printf('zero');
         break;
      case 49: /* 1 */
         printf('one');
         break;
      case 50: /* 2 */
         printf('two');
         break;
      case 51: /* 3 */
         printf('three');
         break;
      case 52: /* 4 */
         printf('four');
         break;
      case 53: /* 5 */
         printf('five');
         break;
      case 54: /* 6 */
         printf('six');
         break;
      case 55: /* 7 */
         printf('seven');
         break;
      case 56: /* 8 */
         printf('eight');
         break;
      case 57: /* 9 */
          printf('nine');
          break;
      default:
          /*In case you enter a symbol, or a letter enter something here*/
   }
   return 0;        
}
```

Comment: 0) use `'0'` instead of `48` 1) add some `break;`s 2) maybe increment `i` as well. 3) `number[i]` is the same as your `*( number + i )`

Comment: I just wanted to say something different than you, i used the decimal Ascii representation, cause answering the samething as you doesn't have any value

Comment: The point is that the '0' notation also works for non-ascii systems. Plus it is more readable for humans; even more than `0x30`. Note: you increment i *before* you have used the first decimal character.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that words are wanted. Read character as string into digits[] and loop much like the following fragment shows. Please add error detection if needed. Do you really need a switch? The following uses much less lines of code.

```
#include "ctype.h"       // isdigit()

int const *digits[] = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four...., ...nine" };

char   number[10];

int   n;
for ( n = 0; n < sizeof(number) && isdigit(number[n]); n++ )
{
    printf( "%s%s", n ? " " : "", digits[number[n] - '0'] );
}

if ( n )
    printf("\n");
```

Disclaimer: not compiled or run.

Comment: Maybe `<ctype.h>` (without semicolon) and `char const *digits[]`. Moreover, the OP seems to ask a solution with `switch` statement.

Comment: You are right... was writing too much shell scripts and perl yesterday.